# Satellite Megaconstellations RF Spectrum usage for free(?)

Tags: radio-communication, law, starlink

As per my understanding, *for terrestrial usage* RF spectrum is auctioned by the governments before telecom operators can avail it for commercial purpose. Seems like a logical way to utilise limited resource (example:https://5g.co.uk/guides/5g-uk-auction/).

In contrast, it looks like allocation (by ITU and corresponding national regulators) of the extra-terrestrial RF spectrum for [proposed commercial Satellite Megaconstellations](https://spacenews.com/spacex-submits-paperwork-for-30000-more-starlink-satellites/) is essentially free? 
Is there any existing licence fee for such commercial operators?

Comment: Last time I heard, they seem to be considering the 5GHz spectrum (and even using wifi as medium)? If so then it's indeed (mostly) free. Another choice is mmW, which, although not free, is quite abundant.

Comment: Governments may auction the RF usage within its territory, but not in space above the atmosphere. Sputnik needed no overflight permission above America. Sputnik transmitted over Russia as well as over America.

Comment: @filo notes in response to my other [question](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/39704/possible-interference-in-rf-spectrum-due-to-space-based-internet/39723#39723) that "_you can carefully reuse the spectrum_" due to highly directional nature of intended frequency spectrum but it is still unconvincing considering high number of satellites proposed by SpaceX and its 8 other competitors and as per this [blog](https://caseyhandmer.wordpress.com/2019/11/02/starlink-is-a-very-big-deal) each satellite beam will be few sq. kms in area on the surface

Comment: @user3528438 :  they seem to be using 10-14GHz  (see [page 4](https://fcc.report/IBFS/SAT-MOD-20181108-00083/1569860.pdf) ) as pointed out by filo in a separate [thread](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/39704/possible-interference-in-rf-spectrum-due-to-space-based-internet/39723)